# Question about exercise 23.3 in TeXbook

Tags: page-breaking, plain-tex

This is exercise 23.3:

> Explain how to change the output routine of plain TeX so that it will produce twice as many pages. The material that would ordinarily go on pages 1, 2, 3, etc., should go onto pages 1, 3, 5, ...; and the even-numbered pages should be entirely blank except for the headline and footline. ...

In plain.tex \output is `{\plainoutput}`, with `\plainoutput` being:

```
\def\plainoutput{\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}%
  \advancepageno
  \ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000 \else\dosupereject\fi}
```

In answer to exercise 23.3 `\output` is `{\plainoutput\blankpageoutput}`, with `\blankpageoutput` being:

```
\def\blankpageoutput{\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline
  \vbox to\vsize{}\makefootline}\advancepageno}
```

In contrast to `\output` from plain.tex, this output routine does not end with `\ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000 \else\dosupereject\fi`.

What is this last "if" for and should `\blankpageoutput` also have this "if"?

Comment: The last `\ifnum` check whether the penalty for inserts on the current page is larger than -20000, i.e. if there are too many inserts held back, and does a supereject, i.e. places all inserts on a suceeding page if this is the case.  `\blankpageoutput` cannot produce any inserts (as the page is completely blank) and can therefore not contribute to the penalty.

Comment: In other words, `\blankpageoutput` doesn't need this "if" because `\plainoutput` is taking care of it (and it won't create new work to be done). But if you write your own output routine, it's something you'll have to think about—if you want to use inserts.

Comment: Do you guys mind to turn your comments into an answer, to put this item out of the unanswered list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the combined answer from the comments below the question:

The last `\ifnum` checks whether the penalty for inserts on the current page is larger than -20000, i.e., if there are too many inserts held back, and does a supereject, i.e., places all inserts on a suceeding page if this is the case. `\blankpageoutput` cannot produce any inserts (as the page is completely blank) and can therefore not contribute to the penalty.

In other words, `\blankpageoutput` doesn't need this `\ifnum` because `\plainoutput` is taking care of it (and it won't create new work to be done). But if you write your own output routine, it's something you'll have to think about — if you want to use inserts.